# Spring Batch Sort Files by File name - Transform specific lines into different POJOs

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am creating a Spring Batch/Spring Boot project with the following flow:

1. It needs to read one or more files (each file should be transformed in a POJO called Archive) from a directory, and for that i am using a MultiResourceReader. But before it starts reading, it needs to sort out the files so they can be processed in the right order.

I was using `Collections.sort` with the implementation used before but couldn't fit it here. Is there something like `Collections.sort` but for resources?

2. Let's suppose the archive has 4 registers. The pattern for the contents of each file is:

First Line - Header // Lines 2 and 3 - Actual Information // Last Line - Trailer

So the program needs to read the first line, transform it into a `Header.class`, for instance and the same should be done for the other types.

If anyone has any suggestions how i could solve this situation i would appreciate the help. Will post more information if required for further understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not implement a `Comparator` and still use `Collections.sort`?

Comment: I do have an implementation of a `Comparator`, but the problem is that i have not been able to get the list of files to use the comparator onto. I need to be able to get the name of the file so i can use the `Comparator`.

Comment: Use a `FactoryBean` to create the sorted list of `Resource`.  Inject the unsorted list into that, then refer to the `FactoryBean` in the configuration of your `MultiResourceItemReader`.

Comment: Tried that but i'm still a noob at Spring and Spring Batch. Could you put that in code please? c:

Answer (score 0):

For question 1.

Create a custom Comparator. See this simple example that just compares the file names.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class MyComparator implements java.util.Comparator {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        FileSystemResource f1 = (FileSystemResource) o1;
        FileSystemResource f2 = (FileSystemResource) o2;
        //Compare the file names. Add any other custom logic here.
        return f1.getFilename().compareTo(f2.getFilename());
    }
}
```

Then include this Comparator as a property in your MultiResourceItemReader.

```
<bean id="customComparator" class="MyComparator"/> 

<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:csv/inputs/sample-*.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
    <property name="comparator" ref="customComparator" />
</bean>
```

For question 2, you need to use an ItemProcessor to convert the lines or process it with special logic. A good example is - http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-hello-world-example/

Comment: How would that configuration be in Java annotations? I have this custom comparator `ArchiveSequenceComparator comparator = new ArchiveSequenceComparator();` and the resources i want to obtain are "Archives".

Comment: Here's the flow that the project should take: [Proj](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B62rTgm0M-K0dFZGTWRjN0w3Yms) i also think that it could grow into more steps...

Comment: I also tried your suggestion on the first question and i wonder if this will work [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B62rTgm0M-K0b1BmNDFTMnR3Y2c) can't tell because the project is not even close to being finished yet.